# Are there any anti-pattern names for writing code like this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, anti-patterns, parameter-object

Here is some code that uses a parameter class to contain the possible parameters to the `Show()` method. The values in this `FooOption` class aren't very related. You can see this by looking at the implementation of `Show()` below. I know this is bad code, but are there any anti-patterns related to doing this?

```
class FooOptions {
  public int? Id { get; set; }
  public string BazContext { get; set; }
  public int? BazId { get; set; }
}

class BarMgr {
  public Bar Show(FooOptions options) {
    if (options == null)
      options = new FooOptions();
    if (options.Id.HasValue)
      return svc.GetBar(options.Id.Value);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.BazContext) && options.BazId.HasValue)
      return svc.GetBar(options.BazContext, options.BazId.Value);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Update:
I know that parameter objects are not an anti-pattern. In my experience, parameter object properties are related. This is the possible anti-pattern that I am trying to locate. setting all three properties makes no sense.

Comment: Using a parameter class isn't an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I already aware of this. I have updated my question to reduce the confusion on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your update, here my answer:
As far as I know, there is no real name for an anti-pattern like this, but there is at least one principle that this method violates:
The [Single-Responsibility-Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

And it really is a problem of the method and not of the parameter object.

Answer (score 5):

It's called the *parameter object pattern*, and it's not considered an antipattern -- it's a good way to deal with methods that would otherwise have too many parameters.

Comment: I'm asking about the properties in the parameter object which have no relation to each other.

Answer (score 2):

There might be an anti-pattern if you use **options** a lot we have something called *feature envy* and is an indication that you might want to move functionality into the actual feature being used.